# Probability problem from FELLER'S book

Tags: probability

4 girls are washing dishes. If there are 4 breakages, find the probability that

a) 3 are caused by one of them.
b) 3 are caused by the youngest.

I am clueless about this one.Please help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One would have to do a substantial amount of experimentation to find a plausible model. So we will use an implausible model. Let the broken dishes be named $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$, and let the washerpersons be A, B, C, D, with A the youngest.

We will assume that dish $i$ is broken by A, B, C, D with equal probabilities, and that the breakages are independent. (Neither of thse assumptions is reasonable.)

List the breakers of $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, in that order. Our sample space has $4^4$ elements, and by assumption these are all equally likely.

We first attack the probability that $3$ breakages are due to A. Which $3$? They can be chosen in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways. And for each of these ways, the breaker of the fourth dish can be chosen in $3$ ways. That gives probability $\frac{12}{256}$.

For the probability that $3$ of the breakages are caused by $1$ person, multiply by $4$.

Comment: we multiply by 4 for the next case as firt we choose any 1 person from the 4 persons ??

Comment: Yes, that's why.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the "breakages" are identical there are $\binom{7}{3}=35$ ways to distribute them (see stars and bars). There   are    $4\cdot4$ ways in which at least $3$ of them are caused by one girl and there are $4$ ways in which at least $3$ are caused by the youngest.

Therefore the answer to $a$ is $\frac{16}{35}$ and the answer to $b$ is $\frac{4}{35}$

Comment: I cannot understand why it came 35.

Comment: i mean how are you writing 7 combination 3

Comment: please explain..thank you

Comment: -1 I don't understand your argumentation. But your numbers contradict the numbers of @André Nicolas, who is right.

Comment: @miracle173:  We are using a different probability model. The model of Jorge Fernandez assumes that if $x_i$ is the number of dishes broken by Person $i$, then all quadruples $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, where $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=4$, are equally likely.  My numbers are "right" in the sense that they follow from the model I used. The numbers in the the answer by Jorge Hernandez are right in that they follow from the model he used.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Thank you for the explanation. Now I understand. This is a very instructive example.

Comment: @Jorge Fernández: My vote on this answer is locked until it is edited. Otherwise I would revoke my downvote due to the comment of André Nicolas.

Comment: I fixed a tpe and changed thedownvote to an upvote